# Topshelf web deploy

Tags: windows-services, webdeploy, topshelf

Is it possible to deploy tepshelf windows service directly to the server? I can't find anything about it.

Windows service is already installed on server I just need a way to update it automatically like I do web sites with web deploy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to deploy Topshelf services directly from Visual Studio like web deploy. It is easy enough to script -- just stop the service, xcopy files to the right unc path, then start the service. There are plenty of deployment tools to help out as well.

Comment: Can you recommend some deployment tools?

Answer (score 0):

Requires custom programming but you can use MSDeploy to deploy a Windows Service and it actually works really well.  We are using MSDeploy for all kinds of components as part of 50+ product pipelines.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/18/deploy-non-web-apps-with-msdeploy/